# Positioning tikz drawings under text

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I am pretty new to latex and tikz, so this might be a simple question, however I am not really able to position my tikz drawing how I want it. 
So I defined my own section command, and what I want i simple: below the section title, I want a fading line. This is what I did so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}    

\newcommand{\mysection}[1]{

\begin{flushleft}  %I want it at the left border of the paper
 \large \sffamily \bfseries \color{blue} #1
 \tikz \filldraw[red, rounded corners = 0.6mm, path fading = east] (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth, 1.3mm);
\end{flushleft}
}


\begin{document}

\mysection{First one}
\end{document}
```

However for me this still looks ugly, because the rectangle is not below the text (the vertical space between is to big). 
I thought I could change it by changing the coordinates of (0,0) onto negative values, but this is not working.

Does someone have some advice?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Your sections won't be numbered? Or only the unnumbered section will have this layout?

Comment: Tikz normally moves the origin to fit the space.  [overlay] will place the origin at the baseline of the current position in the text.  Also, \noindent is generally sufficient.

Comment: Be aware that your section command won't update the table of contents, the headers and allows a page break after it.

Comment: It is on purpose, that the sections are not numbered, but thank you for the helpful comment about the toc. 
So I should add overlay and it would reposition it? Or I misunderstood what you are trying to say.... anyways that is not changing my final result :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution with `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\titleformat{\section}{ \large \sffamily \bfseries \color{blue}}{}{0pt}{}[\raisebox{2ex}{\tikz \filldraw[red, rounded corners = 0.6mm, path fading = east] (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth, 1.3mm);}]

\begin{document}

\section{First one}

\end{document}
```

[image]